# Sharepoint Blog: lost join between categories and post when convert WebPart to XSLT

Tags: sharepoint, blogs, categories

I modify the structure of a default page **category.aspx** from **Sharepoint Blog template** making **XSLT**. When I save the page and execute it in browser, **I lost the connection between categories and posts**, and always shows that there isn't messages in this category. *Do you know how can I restore or how rebuild the connection in XSLT structure?*

Thanks a lot!!!

Xavier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution!

**The WHERE clause of CAML query** that filter the category, **it transforms in a Filter of XSLT with blank value**.
You have create a new parameter from Querystring:
- Click in *DataView common tasks*
- Select the first link: *Filter: Category Is Equal to ''* (here is the blank!!!)
- Select filter and create a new parameter in Value column: write a name for parameter and select querystring and name of parameter in querystring.

Xavier